# Cassandra: Last modified datetime of a row

Tags: cassandra, hector

How can i know the last modified datetime of a row when a column was added to that row in cassandra? I am using hector java api to access cassandra.

Answer (score 5):

The internal timestaps built into each column shouldn't really ever be used. That is why newer CQL api's dont have access to such internal components.

**'Best practice' way to do it** 
You should add a timestamp column which is updated every time you modify the column for which you want the column.

Comment: **'Best practice' way to do it** i think you are right as it seems

Comment: Note there is no timestamp for a row, just for columns. So internal timestamps couldn't even be used for this. The timestamp column is the only way this can be done.